# Create MySQL column with string variable from another column, plus additional information

Tags: php, mysql, linux, excel, bash

What is a way that I could add a column to my table that would include the docID, plus a bunch of static information around it?

For example

```
docID    |    topic   | docURL
________________________________________________________
1        |   Floods   | http://site.com/downloaddoc.php?docID=1

2        |    Etc..   | http://site.com/downloaddoc.php?docID=2
```

I know it seems convoluted to do it this way, but we have to have this particular table downloadable into a CSV to import the data into other programs that use Excel as an input.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do this in the script that generates the .CSV file? You'd have to store that url in only one place instead of repeating it across however many records, which'd be a pain if the url ever has to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET NEW.docURL = CONCAT('http://site.com/downloaddoc.php?docID=',NEW.docID);
END;
```

Comment: @Ryan Valverde Ward: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

After every INSERT you could make an

```
UPDATE table SET docURL = CONCAT('http://site.com/downloaddoc.php?docID=',docID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood but I think you could use concat function in order to concatenate strings and then use a `select into outfile` to export into csv without changing your table structure.